# Intuitive explanation of a derivative with an example

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am having a hard time grasping a concept of derivative intuitively, perhaps due to a lack of a good example of how it can be used in practice. I am looking for an explanation in laymen terms with a practical example that can be deconstructed and would give an idea of how a derivative can be used in practice. I am not looking for mathematical proof or strict mathematical definition.

Here is my current understanding, please point out where it is correct or incorrect intuitively:

Let's say that we have $y$ (dependent variable or output) and $x$ (independent variable or input).
If we have a function of   $y=x^{3}$. Does derivative tell us by how much the output of a function (dependent variable $y$) when we change input (independent variable $x$) by a certain amount ($dx$)? In other words, derivative tells us how sensitive the function is to the changes in its input.

P.S. I could not find a satisfactory explanation of this question anywhere on stack exchange.

Comment: I think you should not use the word "sensitive", as it corresponds to another meaning rather than just the how quick is it changing.

Comment: Yes, it does do that.  But I think it is easier to think of it as this:  A function is constantly changing, sometimes fast sometimes slow.  The derivative simply tells you the rate of change of the function is *at any particular instant*.

Comment: Real life example.  Drop a ball off tall building.  It $t$ seconds it will be at a position $-3.26 t^3 meters$.  The derivative is $-9.8 t^2 meters/second$ which tells you how fast the ball is falling at $t$ seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Yes of course the derivative of a function represents the **rate of change** $\Delta y$ of the y coordinates for a change $\Delta x$ of x coordinates as the increment becomes "small", that is

$$f'(x)=lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$$

**Slope** could be a very intuitive concept to understand derivatives. We can indeed think to the function as a mountain track, then the derivative at a point is the slope (i.e. the slope of the tangent line) exactly at that point.

[image]

Comment: Please refrain from using the mathematical definition, I am looking for an intuitive explanation with a practical example. Thank you.

Comment: @verkter Ok don't look the symbols and formulas. I think that slope is a very intuitive concept, you can think su the function as a road in a mountain, thus the derivative is the slope (i.e. the slope of the tangent line) exactly at a point of the road.

Comment: " I am looking for an intuitive explanation"  Most people consider "rate of change" and "slope of tangent line" as intuitive.  If you don't, then you need to tell us why it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x$ is a measurement of time and $y=y(x)$ is the distance travelled by a car at time $x$ along a straight line from a starting point. The car may stop or reverse; it need not be always moving forward, or even moving at all. The $average$ speed in the forward direction, over the time interval from time $x$ to time $x+d$ (with $d\ne 0$) is $\frac {y(x+d)-y(d)}{(x+d)-x}=\frac {y(x+d)-y(x)}{d}.$ Keeping $x$ fixed and letting $d\to 0,$  this tends to  $y'(x),$ which we call the  speed "at time $x.$ " It is the rate of change of the car's position at time $x.$ If $y'(x)=0$ it means the car was stopped at that moment. If $y'(x)<0$ the car was  moving in reverse at time $x.$